# php contact form not sending radio info

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this php contact form and it works great but when I try to add some radio code in it; it does not work. Meaning sends the email but not the radio part. How can I code it to work.

index.html

```
<body onLoad="randomNums();">

  <div class="contactForm">
<br>
  <table width="42%">
  <tr>
    <td width="12%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="88%"><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" style="width:374px;"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<br>
<table width="63%">
  <tr>
    <td width="9%"><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td width="26%"><strong>Phone</strong> (Optional)</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="32%"><input type="text" id="email" name="email"></td>
    <td width="33%"><input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

    <br />

  <strong>Message</strong>

    <br />

  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="12" cols="64"></textarea>

    <br />
I'm a:  <input type="radio" name="type" value="Other" checked="checked" /> Other
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Student" /> Student
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Faculty" /> Faculty/Staff Member<br />
    <br />

  <strong>Please add these numbers:</strong>

  <span id="digit1"></span> +

  <span id="digit2"></span> =

  <input type="text" id="answer" size="2">

    <br />

    <br />

    <div id="status"><button type="button" id="myBtn" onClick="ajax_postContact();">Send Now</button></div>

</div>

</body>
```

Contact.js

```
function ajax_postContact(){

    var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;

    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;

    var ph = document.getElementById("phone").value;

    var em = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);

    var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);

    ///// error checking ////

    var sum = digit1 + digit2;

    if(answer == null || answer == ""){

        alert("Please add the numbers");

        return false;

    }

    else if(answer != sum){

        alert("Your answer to the math problem is wrong. Please try again.");

        return false;

    }

    else if(fn == null || fn == ""){

        alert("Please type your name");

        return false;

    }

    else if(em == null || em == ""){

        alert("Please type your email address");

        return false;

    }

    else if(msg == null || msg == ""){

        alert("Please leave a message");

        return false;

    }

    else{

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "parse_contact.php";

    var vars = "first_name="+fn+"&phone="+ph+"&email="+em+"&message="+msg;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){

    var return_data = hr.responseText;

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;

    }

}

    hr.send(vars);

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src='images/loaderblue.gif' alt='Loader'>";

    document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";

    document.getElementById("phone").value = "";

    document.getElementById("email").value = "";

    document.getElementById("message").value = "";

    document.getElementById("answer").value = "";

    }

}
```

parse_contact.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];


    $regex = '/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([\.a-zA-Z0-9_-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+(\.a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6})$/';

   if((!$first_name) || (!$email) || (!$msg)){
        echo 'Oops! Please fill in all fields to submit the form';
        exit();
    }else if(!preg_match($regex, $email)){
        echo 'Sorry, that is not a valid email address, please try using another';
        exit();
    }else{
        $first_name = strip_tags(stripslashes($first_name));
        $msg = strip_tags(stripslashes($msg));
        $phone = preg_replace('/^0-9.-/','',$phone);

        $to = "cc-wp@hotmail.com";
        $from = $email;
        $subject = "You have a message from your website";
        ///email body ///
        $message = "
        Name:$first_name    Phone:$phone

        Email:$email

        Feedback Comment:
        $msg

        $type";
        //// set headers ////
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "/r/n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text' . "/r/n";
        $headers .= 'From: $from'. "\r\n";
        /// send email now ///
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f cc-wp@hotmail.com');
        echo "Thanks, for your feedback";
        exit();
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: add id to the input type

Comment: I have change it to `<br />
I'm a:  <input type="radio" id="other" name="a" value="Other" checked="checked" /> Other
        <input type="radio" id="student" name="a" value="Student" /> Student
        <input type="radio" id="faculty" name="a" value="Faculty" /> Faculty/Staff Member<br />
    <br />`

Comment: As for the php code `if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];
 $sel = $_POST['a'];` and still not working

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the `type` from your radio inputs in your POST request.

Your code snippet:

```
var vars = "first_name="+fn+"&phone="+ph+"&email="+em+"&message="+msg;

hr.open("POST", url, true);
```

You are encoding the other inputs except the radio type.

Comment: What do you mean I'm lost now.

Comment: your code is grabbing each form element like this: `document.getElementById("email").value;` and then passing it to your AJAX call. But you're not doing the same thing for the "type" radio inputs. Honestly, the code in your question is very ugly and is way too complicated for something that should be really simple.

Answer (score 0):

**Code edited:**

```
function ajax_postContact() {

var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;

var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

var fn = document.getElementById("first_name").value;

var ph = document.getElementById("phone").value;

var em = document.getElementById("email").value;

var type = document.getElementsByName("type").value;

var digit1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit1").innerHTML);

var digit2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("digit2").innerHTML);

///// error checking ////

var sum = digit1 + digit2;

if (answer == null || answer == "") {

    alert("Please add the numbers");

    return false;

} else if (answer != sum) {

    alert("Your answer to the math problem is wrong. Please try again.");

    return false;

} else if (fn == null || fn == "") {

    alert("Please type your name");

    return false;

} else if (em == null || em == "") {

    alert("Please type your email address");

    return false;

} else if (msg == null || msg == "") {

    alert("Please leave a message");

    return false;

} else if (type == null || type == "") {

    alert("Please select  the type");

    return false;

} else {

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "parse_contact.php";

    var vars = "first_name=" + fn + "&phone=" + ph + "&email=" + em + "&message=" + msg + "&type=" + type;

    hr.open("POST", url, true);

    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

            var return_data = hr.responseText;

            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = return_data;

        }

    }

    hr.send(vars);

    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "<img src='images/loaderblue.gif' alt='Loader'>";

    document.getElementById("first_name").value = "";

    document.getElementById("phone").value = "";

    document.getElementById("email").value = "";

    document.getElementById("message").value = "";

    document.getElementById("answer").value = "";

    document.getElementByName("type").value = "";

}}
```